# Single code base for mobile and web

Tags: angular, reactjs, react-native, nativescript

We are going to begin a project for our company a order status application that will be hosted as web app as well as android/ios app.We started researching and came with conclusion to start with React and React Native or Angular and Native Script.Can anyone suggest on which one to pick as the ultimate goal was to maintain single code base for both web and mobile.

[Edit 1]:Thanks guys.Many of you suggested for Ionic / Cordova , PWA but all these seems to build an hybrid app but i was searching for something like a native app which can run on browser as well.For Example in react native you have this kind of architecture where the JavaScript file is converted to a true native component(Android/IOS).But the problem with react and react-native is there is no single code base.

Comment: Just an option `angular` and `PWA`

Comment: May I ask why you didn't go with Ionic instead of Nativescript?

Comment: When I checked out Ionic, I got the impression it is not possible to have one codebase, because Ionic and Cordova that it's based on, are using a stack-of-pages pattern (resembling the way mobile operating systems save application data) to organize the structure, while in Angular you would normally not have multiple app.components, but just a single one that is bootstrapping your app with a navbar, footer and all the other elements that are always present

Comment: @Phil with Ionic it will be more of an hybrid app instead of a true native app.The reason i went for react-native was its way of using the js code to native component.Ionic or a Phone gap will be a more hybrid approach then a native app.

Answer (score 6):

I have done a single code based package for a **ReactJS** and **React-Native**. I can tell you my solution and experience with this.

**UI**

Both frameworks use the same syntax to describe the UI (**JSX**). If you go into more detail you will see that there are several differences:

- ReactJS: `<div/>`
- React-Native: `<View/>`
  That means there will be always a "*framework-specific*" part in your application/architecture. To minimize the specific code to only the differences you can use **JSX** to provide props to components like *styles*, *data*, or event *functions*.

**Functionality**

React-Native uses/contains the ReactJS framework and all runs in a JavaScript virtual machine. So for "*non native/ui functionality*" you can use good old JavaScript written functionalities or packages provided (e.g. via npm) functionalities across both apps (ReactJS && React-Native)

**How to use one code for both apps**

Now we now functionality is no problem. But how to get across the UI specifics. My solution was to write some kind of pseudo code for framework specific components:

1. For each framework write a pseudo class wich stands for your
   component. The following example shows some class rejecting to RN
   [View](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html) class:

*My implementation of a very simple View component on **ReactJS** side*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class View_Wrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.props.style}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default View_Wrapper;
```

*My implementation of a very simple View component on **React-Native** side*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

class View_Wrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={this.props.style}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default View_Wrapper;
```

2. Create a own project for your **shared-code** ([Create project](https://medium.com/@fastlane80/setup-react-js-with-npm-babel-6-and-webpack-in-under-1-hour-1a714f973506)) and provide your written *View* components to it. That means you import your *shared-code* in your React or React-Native project and give the *shared-code* project your *framework-specific* components.

*My implementation of a class inside my **shared-code** project wich holds the view for me. In this code you can reuse the **View** component and write your UI with this component. That means in React there would be a `div` against what React-Native would contain a `View`*

```
let View = undefined;

const registerView = (View) => {
  UIProvider.View = View
};

const getView = () => {
  return UIProvider.View;
};

let UIProvider = {
  View: View
};

//Functions for component registration
UIProvider.registerView = registerView;

//Functions to receive shared components
UIProvider.getView = getView;

export {UIProvider};
```

**Problems i got through this way**

- Key to use the components is to break everything down to blank JavaScript and use this in your React or React-Native projects. Maybe its owing through my missing experience in webpack but i got lots of trouble with this. They were cause because if you build up a React app with create-react-app the webpack config is done for you and it's not that easy to break things up to the level they want.
- Another point is you should use [High-Order-Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to use your components in your shared-code package/library or whatever. If you are new to it it can be confusing at the beginning but gives you a big value if you use and understand it.

**Furthermore reading**

- [Christian Sepulveda - Share Code between React and React Native Apps](https://hackernoon.com/code-reuse-using-higher-order-hoc-and-stateless-functional-components-in-react-and-react-native-6eeb503c665)
- [Ihor Burlachenko - Code sharing between React and React-Native](http://ihor.burlachenko.com/code-sharing-between-react-and-react-native-applications/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: No problem :) Its just a small outlook of what is possible and what not, which problems can come,... 

I worked around 2 weeks now on this and if you follow the instructions you !can! reach shared code in a good, reusable and maintainable way.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to pick React for web and React Native for mobile, It makes your developers to learn once and write for any platform. And I personally don't suggest a single code base for all the platforms as it makes things messy. I would rather maintain 3 code bases for web, android and IOS (or at-least two code bases for web and mobile) and will share the common code.

You can use hybrid apps to have a single code base but be mindful that these are wrapped applications and thus performance drops.

You can also use the same code base for mobile and web using react-native-web.

Comment: I agree. Atleast 2 code bases. I've seen very messy Mobile deployments with JS frameworks, causing clients to revert back to (Java/Kotlin) for Android, and (Swift/ObjC) for IOS. For web... Yes React!

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for a single code base for web/ios/android. The easiest is building a webapp.

Some options are:

- Progressive Web App
- Hybrid applications (like Ionic)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. [React Native for Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)

Already being used by big companies out there, and it looks very promising to me. To be able to even share presentation code is quite amazing!

Answer (score 0):

The best stack would be react for web and react native for mobile , Because react uses virtual dom which speeds up your website. And when it comes to single code base and optimised APK size and community support available react-native is way far ahead of native-script.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PWA or you can use "React Native Web":
https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Answer (score 0):

Both have their ups & downs. But I am noticing more developers are tilting towards React. However after working in both, I will tell you keep a keen eye on **Flutter**. Cause I find, the look, feel & performance of the app built using **Flutter + Dart**, to be have an edge over both. BUT like me, every developer is only holding back because as of today their WEB part is still in beta.